# Resource linking failed when setting app:textColorHint for TextInputLayout of Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I am creating a style for my `TextInputLayout` like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="textColorHint">@color/white</item> //This line is not getting recognized. 
    </style>
```

According to the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/#filled-text-field),

> **android:textColorHint** is hint color.
>
> **app:hintTextColor** is collapsed (floating) hint color.

The issue is happening with **styles** only. If I set the `app:hintTextColor` directly to the `TextInputLayout`, everything is working fine.

I am using the material design:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

I tested it on the sable version `1.1.0` as well. Still, the same issue is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style **change** the item:

```
<item name="textColorHint">@color/white</item>
```

**to**

```
<item name="hintTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

Something like:

```
<style name="MyFilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele! What a shame that I made a typing error there :)